# Adding a node to a tree and sorting by post order not working

Tags: c, sorting, tree

So for one of my assignments, we have to make a tree, add strings to it, and then sort it so that they are printed in descending order. The code all looks right and compiles fine, but when I run my program ./addnodetest, it doesn't print anything when it should be printing out the sorted nodes in descending order. Any reason why that may be?

Here's the function treesort.c, where it sorts the node added into the tree based on its value:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "treesort.h"

/** Adds a new node to the tree. If the pointer to the passed in node is NULL, allocates a new node, puts 
 * the value into it, and returns a pointer to the new node. If the pointer is not NULL, compares the new 
 * value to the value in the node pointed to, then invokes the function       recursively on the left or right 
 * child as appropriate.
 * @param *current_tnode Pointer to an existing node
 * @param value A new value to be add to the tree
 * @return The new node
 */
Tnode *add_tnode(Tnode *current_tnode, char* value) {
  if (current_tnode == NULL) {
    Tnode *node = (Tnode*) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    node->leftchild = NULL;
    node->string = value;
    node->rightchild = NULL;
    current_tnode = node;
  }

  if (strcmp(current_tnode->string, value) > 0) {
    add_tnode(*(current_tnode->leftchild), value);
  }

  if (strcmp(current_tnode->string, value) < 0) {
    add_tnode(*(current_tnode->rightchild), value);
  }

  while (strcmp(current_tnode->string, value) == 0) {
    return current_tnode;
  }

  return current_tnode;
}
```

Here's the traversetree.c function, where I call postorder on the tree so that it prints out the tree in descending order:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "treesort.h"

/** Traverses the tree, then prints out the values in the appropriate order.
 * @param node Tree to be sorted.
 */
void postorder(Tnode *node) {
  if (node != NULL) {
    postorder(*(node->leftchild));
    postorder(*(node->rightchild));
    printf("%s\n", node->string);
  }
}
```

Here's the main program addnodetest.c, where I am making a root node initialized to NULL (had to do this for the assignment, and I think could be the issue) then calls add_tnode for each character in the array (adding them to the tree) and prints them out using post order:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "treesort.h"

int main() {
  Tnode *root = NULL;
  int i; // Loop counter
  char* array[] = {"m","j","p","h","f","t","c","w","z","a"};

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    add_tnode(root, array[i]);
  }

  postorder(root);
  return 0; // Success!
}
```

Here's the header file treesort.h, where I define the struct node and the two functions I made:

```
#ifndef TREESORT_H
#define TREESORT_H

/** Struct to define a node
 */
struct node {
  char* string; // Pointer to the C-style string that the node holds
  void** leftchild; // Pointer to the left child of the node
  void** rightchild; // "Pointer to the right child of the node
};

typedef struct node Tnode;

// Function prototypes

Tnode *add_tnode(Tnode *current_tnode, char* value);
void postorder(Tnode *node);

#endif
```

And here's the part of my makefile you would need if you wanted to compile it:

```
all: treesort addnodetest traversetree

treesort: treesort.o addnodetest.o traversetree.o
    gcc -g treesort.o addnodetest.o traversetree.o -o treesort

treesort.o: treesort.c treesort.h
    gcc -g -Wall -c treesort.c

addnodetest: addnodetest.o treesort.o traversetree.o
    gcc -g addnodetest.o treesort.o traversetree.o -o addnodetest

addnodetest.o: addnodetest.c treesort.h
    gcc -g -Wall -c addnodetest.c

traversetree: traversetree.o addnodetest.o treesort.o
    gcc -g traversetree.o addnodetest.o treesort.o -o traversetree

traversetree.o: traversetree.c treesort.h
    gcc -g -Wall -c traversetree.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f treesort
    rm -f addnodetest
    rm -f traversetree
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why void**?

Comment: Been using void** for other pointers in my code so that it could theoretically point to anything (like an integer instead of a string). Should I not be using void**?

Answer (score 1):

`add_tnode` currently never adds anything to the tree passed in, because it can never modify the pointer `current_tnode` which was passed by value to it.

Either you need to use the return value of `add_tnode` like this:

```
root = add_tnode(root, array[i]);
```

Or you need to change the function to take a pointer to a pointer like this:

```
add_tnode(&root, array[i]);
```

You should also be aware that you are using `leftchild` and `rightchild` incorrectly.  They should be of type `struct node *`, and everywhere they are used should be adjusted accordingly.  Right now, if you managed to add one node, the next call to `add_tnode` would dereference NULL.

Comment: Thanks!! Along with a few other minor edits, that fixed it! :D